# Но горячей дружбой связаны мы с то-бо-ю!

Tags: орфография, дефис, цитата

Является ли такое употребление дефиса орфографически допустимым для «Песенки кота и пирата»?

> Но горячей дружбой связаны мы с то-бо-ю!

Comment: Но горячей дружбой связаны\
Мы с тобою.

Comment: Скажите, как его зовут?\

Бу! Ра! Ти! Но!\
Буратино!

Comment: Стихи Энтина погугли. https://allpoetry.ru/allpoetry/entin-yu-s и https://www.kino-teatr.ru/kino/movie/sov/5643/song/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Юрия Энтина [слова песни](https://l-hit.com/ru/32073) написаны так:

*Ты и я такие разные.

Я и ты такие разные,

Но горячей дружбой связаны

Мы **с тобою.***

Оформление каких-либо слов с помощью "внутреннего" дефиса, конечно же, возможно.
Об этом говорится в ПАС ([**Дефис**](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=59#pp59); понятнее, чем у Лопатина, и не скажешь).

> **3.** В любых текстах (чаще в художественных и публицистических) дефис может использоваться в выразительных целях: <...>
> **б)** для передачи произношения по слогам с разными целями (произнесение говорящим незнакомого слова, смысловое выделение важного слова и др.), напр.: ...*Только всё-таки это был очаровательный сон, о-ча-ро-ва-тельный сон!..* (Дост.)...
> **в)** для передачи протяжного звучания гласных, раскатистого **р** и других особенностей произношения, напр.: *Антропка! Антропка-а-а!.. — кричал он с упорным и слезливым отчаянием, долго, долго вытягивая последний слог* (Т.)...

*Он ударил в медный таз

И вскричал: «Кара-барас!»*
К. Чуковский. Мойдодыр

Или у того же Энтина в "Бременских музыкантах":
*Мы рраз-бо-бо-ой-ой-йники!

Разбойники! Разбойники!

Пиф-паф! И вы — покойники!

Покойники! Покойники!*

Если для особенного произношения чужих слов нужно поставить дефисы, — ставьте, но не оформляйте как цитату (это будет нарушением авторской орфографии).
Возможно также, думаю, эти особенности отметить в ремарке.